# Why does my valid regex pattern doesn't work in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to import files from a folder that match a particular pattern:

1. It must contain "AllRecipients" and
2. It needs to be a ".csv"file.

For example the file: "AllRecipients_XYZ324_S_test.csv"

Using online regex testers, the following pattern works just fine:

```
^(?=.*AllRecipients)(?=.*csv).*$
```

However, in R, I'm getting this error:

```
invalid 'pattern' regular expression
```

This is the full line in the script:

```
temp = list.files(path="..", pattern="^(?=.*AllRecipients)(?=.*csv).*$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Any ideas why this isn't working in R?

Comment: Please try the simpler pattern `pattern=".*AllRecipients.*csv$"`

Comment: I believe you're complicating: `pattern = "AllRecipients.*\\.csv$"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.files` pattern parameter uses the [TRE regex syntax](https://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/), so lookaheads aren't available.

But this isn't really a problem since you don't need lookaheads at all:

```
list.files(path="..", pattern="AllRecipients.*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Note also that your original pattern was wrong since it matches even when csv isn't at the end of filename.